# How to determine path of resource files on different computers? - C#

Tags: c#, path, resources

I am writing a simple game for my course work. The application contains many pictureboxes with no images inside them. I also have a directory with needed pictures in the Visual Studio project debug folder. I need to put the pictures' paths into an array in my program to then randomly insert them into pictureboxes.

The problem is I don't know how it would work on another computer, so I can't organize all the things. The game must be launched without using Visual Studio there, only exe file. Should I first make the installation setup of my unfinished program, or something like this, and then place the application with resources somewhere on disk to know where all my pictures would be on any computer? And then maybe I could determine the exact path where I would take all the pictures and put them into the array. Or vice versa... I'm totally confused with this.

Here what I use to fill the array:

```
string[] spritePaths = Directory.GetFiles(/*paths*/);
```

Comment: you said "I need to put the pictures' paths into an array in my program". Is this a requirement or is this simply what you are currently doing?

Comment: You could add your images as embedded resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to distribute the pictures in a folder with the .exe file? If so, you could use a relative path to get all of the pictures.

```
    string[] spritePaths = Directory.GetFiles("pictureFolder");
```

As DangerZone suggests, you could also add your images as embedded resources.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

- Specify the path to the folder of images as a command line argument. Then you can launch it from CMD, or create a shortcut and specify the arguments there.
- Add a `TextBox` for the user to enter the path to the images.
- Add a browse button or menu button and allow the user to search for the folder using a dialog.
- Use a predefined location, such as an images folder next to the exe.